# Background Changer application takes too much memory

Tags: c#, image, memory, background, slideshow

I'm working on a background changing application. Part of the application is a slideshow with 3 image previews (3 image boxes). Previous, Current and Next image. The problem is that each time the timer ticks the application takes about 8 MB of memory space. I know its most likely caused by the image drawing class but I have no idea how to dispose of the images that I'm not using.

UPDATE:
Thank you so much. I need to adjucst the code you have provided a little bit but it works now. When I tried using the dispose method before I used it on completely different object.
Thank you.

It works in the following order.

1. Load multiple images

   - retrieve image path
2. set time interval in which the images will be changed
3. start the timer
4. with each timer tick the timer does the following

   ```
   pictureBoxCurr.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(_filenames.ElementAt(_currNum));
   pictureBoxPrev.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(_filenames.ElementAt(_currNum - 1));
   pictureBoxNext.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(_filenames.ElementAt(_currNum + 1));
   ```

Each time new previews are shown the memory usage takes another 8MB or so. I have no Idea what exactly is taking that space.

Please let me know if you know what is causing the problem or have any clues.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend calling the following code at every timer tick, prior to changing the images.

```
pictureBoxCurr.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
pictureBoxPrev.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
pictureBoxNext.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
```

This will free the unmanaged image resources immediately, rather than waiting for the Garbage Collector.

Comment: Tried. I got the following exception

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Check to see if each image is null prior to disposing.  If it is null, do not dispose.

Comment: It worked. I only had to adjust it a little bit. Thank you so much.